# returning std::vector iterator - performance differences in iteration methods?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, iteration, stdvector

Take a look at the following data structure (ignore the purpose, as this is about the iteration part):

```
template<typename T>
struct CacheContainer {

  std::unordered_map<shared::object_id_t, T> cache_map;
  std::vector<T> cache_vector;

  void insert( shared::object_id_t idx, T obj ) {
    cache_vector.push_back(obj);
    cache_map.insert(std::make_pair(idx, obj)); 
  }

  T at(shared::object_id_t idx) {
    return cache_map.at(idx);
  }

  // use vector for iteration
  typename std::vector<T>::iterator begin() { return cache_vector.begin(); }
  typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator begin() const { cache_vector.cbegin(); }
  typename std::vector<T>::iterator end() { return cache_vector.end(); }
  typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator cend() const { return cache_vector.cend(); }    
};
```

When iterating with a range-based for loop, there's a significant loss in performance iterating over the container directly, as compared to iterating over the vector directly.

See the following example:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a77e8ecd863d6fad

I'm a bit puzzled where the performance difference between 1.) and 2.) stems from.

It's even more significant on my local machine:

(MBP i7, Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2))

```
Accum Time 1.) - 500500 0.000648
Accum Time 2.) - 500500 2e-06
Accum Time 3.) - 500500 1e-06
```

Anybody got an idea why returning the iterator the way i do it above costs so much performance ?

Comment: The timings on coliru are almost the same.  Your talking about the difference of `.000003` and `.000002`.  Thats a `.000001` difference.  Almost anything could cause that slight change.

Comment: @NathanOliver totally, but as i wrote, on my machine, the difference is somewhat significant ... unfortunately i can't reproduce it that way on coliru.

Comment: What happens if you flip 1 and 2 around so 2 runs first.  Does 1 still run the same or does 2 now run slower?

Comment: little tipo: typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator (c)begin()

Comment: @NathanOliver you're right, the difference remains the same, independent of the order ...

Comment: @NathanOliver time difference ~30% is significant enough to not ignore it to my taste

Comment: @wtom When the difference is less than a millisecond - anything (not necessarily related to the code, that is being run) could cause it. One would need to increase the testcase, so it, at the very least, takes seconds (minutes are even better), so that performance issues (if any) are better pronounced.

Comment: @EllipsenPark What happens if you change your creation loop to `for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)` so we get more samples?

Comment: Your sample data size is a bit small and you are close to the timer limits. See [this run](https://wandbox.org/permlink/spjrKYP9bE1jEara). Increasing data size by [factor 100 still gives quite random results](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TwWAgGjy6H60Nexz) [see here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lGSCOGHuve1nQycw).

Comment: @NathanOliver yep i < 10000000 gives ~1% differences. but cause is interesting anyway. let's imagine func doing 1000 iterations and func is called 1000 times.

Comment: Also remember there is AS IF rule, so compiler can outsmart your test.

Comment: @wtom Most likely there is an optimization bug somewhere.  I'm not able to reproduce the OP's results and all my test are pretty consistent.

Comment: Ok, when i increase the number of samples, the time converges towards the same  number for all methods. I guess i didn't think about larger numbers as in my use case, i typically won't exceed a few hundred, so it probably doesn't even matter that much. Still interesting.

Comment: @EllipsenPark btw why typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator **begin()** not **c**begin?

Comment: @wtom just a typo ...